# How do the Cybernetic organism's cells receive nourishment?

Tags: the-terminator-series

Countless times we've been shown the Terminator's biological parts healing after damage. For example, in Terminator 2 after John and the T-800/101 rescue Sarah from Pescadero Mental Hospital and they're fixing their wounds:

> *Sarah:* Will these heal up?
>   *T-101:* Yes
>   *Sarah:* Good. If you can't pass for human you're not much good to us.

So the tissues are definitely 'alive' in that sense. They even heal quicker than human injuries (Sarah Connor Chronicles):

> *John:* You're healing.
>   *Cameron:* Faster than you.

*But how exactly do these cells receive nourishment?* There's obviously blood to carry nutrients and oxygen, as well as white blood cells to stave off infections. I'm assuming there's a pump somewhere pushing it around the body, but  where do the oxygen and nutrients required to keep the cells alive come from?

Comment: I am guessing the skin is like grass in a way. They can get oxygen through  just being exposed to air and that really is the only thing they need. I highly doubt they are as efficient as say human cells. I mean come on, the skin is only needed to disguise them until the Terminator gets to where it needs to go. After it reaches its goal, even if the skin burns down, the metal endo skeleton keeps it safe until it is either blown apart or it takes out a good chunk of human lives, before being blown apart..